# update single field directly gave value in update function yii2

Tags: yii2

i am new in yii2 i try to develop a online leave application.database table is leavetable .in this case my table consist a field named recommendation that is not in active view .recommendation field already  has a value pending, when  i clicking update button i want to change only a single field(recommendation) that is value  pending changed to recommended. what can i do

```
  public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->start_date = strtotime($model->start_date);
        $model->start_date = date('Y-m-d',$model->start_date);
        $model->end_date = strtotime($model->end_date);
        $model->end_date = date('Y-m-d',$model->end_date);
        $model->date_of_request = strtotime($model->date_of_request);
        $model->date_of_request = date('Y-m-d',$model->date_of_request);
        //$model->start_date = date_format($model->start_date,'Y-m-d');
       if($model->save()){
         return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
       }else{
          return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
         ]);



       }
   } else {
       return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
      ]);


  //new line
```

}
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For updating only one field value you have to make following changes in `actionUpdate()`

```
public function actionUpdate($id) {
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->recommendation = 'recommended';
        if($model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }
        else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    } 
    else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    } 
}
```